# How to get controls click from a video element?

Tags: html, video

Adding the following Event I can retrieve the video player control click just fine:

```
objectVideo.addEventListener("click", function () ...
```

but it doesn't fire if the user clicks in the controls panel (the default html5 video control).

How can I get the click event for the control?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, what you want to do is capture the first click that the user makes on the video element, to tell when they start interacting with that element.

You won't be able to get click events directly from the player controls because they are not standardized across browsers. What I recommend instead is that you capture the first click using a transparent div over the video:

Make a transparent, absolutely positioned div over the video like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <video ...></video>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("click", function () ...
```

and make sure to disable the overlay after the first click!